# SQL: Selecting from multiple databases and Order by common field?

Tags: sql

I am trying to display rows from each of these tables, from my db, onto an html page.  How do I select and order each by the same common row, which is the Position row?

```
$con=odbc_connect('rdt','','');
$sql= "SELECT * FROM [Drive Errors],[Drive List] ORDER BY COALESCE[Position]ASC"; 

$rs=odbc_exec($con,$sql);
if (!$rs)
    {echo("Error");}
```

I get this error: The specified field '[Position]' could refer to more than one table listed in the FROM clause of your SQL statement

Thanks

PS:The position row has the same data in all the tables

Comment: Show us the table structures. Are the other columns also common? or are you trying to JOIN them in some way you forgot to add there?

Answer (score 0):

Try a join statement

```
SELECT * FROM table1
JOIN table2 ON table1.commonfield = table2.commonfield
```